# How to pass multiple parameters from different controller functions on single model function

Tags: php, codeigniter, model, controller

I have two controller functions both need one model function but when I pass parameters to single model function it shows me an error, I need help if there is another method to pass parameters

Controller

```
public function view_files()
{
    $assignment_id='1255';
    $data['files'] = $this->AdminModel->getRows111();
    $this->load->view('admin/view_files', $data);
}

function download_test1(){
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);

    if (empty($id)){
           redirect(base_url());
    }

    $data = $this->AdminModel->getRows111($id);
    $filename =$data['assignment_file_name'];
    $fileContents = file_get_contents(base_url('upload/'. 
         $data['assignment_file_name'])); 

    force_download($filename, $fileContents);

}
```

**Model**

```
public function getRows111($id=''){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where('assignment_id','1255');
    $this->db->from('tbl_assignments_files');

    if($id){
        $this->db->where('assignment_file_id',$id);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->row_array();

    }else{
       $query = $this->db->get();
       $result = $query->result_array();

    }

    return !empty($result)?$result:false;

   }
}
```

function 1

```
$data['files'] = $this->AdminModel->getRows111(assignment_id);
```

function 2

```
$data = $this->AdminModel->getRows111($id);
```

model *by doing this, shows error*

```
public function getRows111($id='',$assignment_id){
```

Comment: be more specific for the error.

Comment: This is the error: Too few arguments to function AdminModel::getRows111()

Answer (score 2):

```
public function getRows111($id='',$assignment_id=""){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('tbl_assignments_files');

        //if assignment_id is not empty it will add where clause to statement
        if($assignment_id != ""){
           $this->db->where('assignment_id',$assignment_id);
        }
       //if id is not empty it will add where clause to statement
        if($id != ""){
            $this->db->where('assignment_file_id',$id);   
        }
      $query = $this->db->get();
      $result = $query->result_array();

        return !empty($result)?$result:false;
    }
}
```

**To call model function first parameter will be $id and second will be $assignment_id**

**To call model function by $id**

```
$data = $this->AdminModel->getRows111($id);
```

OR

```
 $data = $this->AdminModel->getRows111($id,'');
```

**To call function by $assignment_id**

```
$data = $this->AdminModel->getRows111("",$assignment_id);
```

**To call function by both $id and $assignment_id**

```
 $data = $this->AdminModel->getRows111($id,$assignment_id);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: generating problem with downloading

Comment: yeah, problem is when i go to this page or even refresh it, the .docx files gets automatic downloaded without clicking maybe its an error with force_download(). suggest me if you have any idea

Comment: i.e i have 3 files in which 2 are images and 1 is .docx image file gets downloaded only if i click on download button whereas .docx starts downloading on page refresh

Comment: where can i see force_download() function ?

Answer (score 1):

you are using your function  wrong,
base on the `function getRows111` it does have 2 parameters need the `$id` and `$assignment_id`

proper used would be like this,

```
$this->AdminModel->getRows111($id, $assignment_id);
```

I suggest for your function to make it more flexible is this.

```
public function getRows111($array){
    $id = $array[0];
    $assignment_id = $array[1];
}
```

then call the function using with array parameter

```
$this->AdminModel->getRows111([$id, $assignment_id]);
```

to handle the array and you want it to be more flexible.

```
public function getRows111($array){
    $id = isset($array['id']) ? $array['id'] : "";
    $assignment_id = isset($array['assignment_id']) ? $array['assignment_id'] : "";
}
```

call the function like this

```
$this->AdminModel->getRows111(
   ['id' => $id,
    'assignment_id' => $assignment_id
]);

// if you want just the id
$this->AdminModel->getRows111(['id' => $id]);

// or the the assignment id

$this->AdminModel->getRows111(['assignment_id' => $assignment_id]);
```

Comment: thanx dude, trying

Comment: The problem is i have two different controller functions, i passed array parameters still throwing too few arguments for my model function

Comment: can I see how you used it?

Comment: I passed assignment id to 2nd function like this                                             `$this->download_test1($assignment_id);``` and in 2nd function like this          
 ` $data = $this->AdminModel->getRows111($id,$assignment_id);`           ,  model function                                                                                             
 `public function getRows111($array){
    $id = isset($array['id']) ? $array['id'] : "";
    $assignment_id = isset($array['assignment_id']) ? $array['assignment_id'] : "";}`

Comment: the function `getRows111` only accept array, so it should be like this `$data = $this->AdminModel->getRows111(['id'=>$id, 'assignment_id'=>$assignment_id]);`